Is it possible to find $a_i,b_i,c_i>0$ ($i=1,2,3$) s.t. $a_1b_1c_1=1/27,a_1+a_2+a_3=1$ and $a_1b_1+a_2b_3\geq1/3$ (+cyclic shifts $a\to b\to c\to a$)?
Question 1: is it possible to find $a_1,..,a_3, b_1,.., b_3, c_1,.., c_3>0$ s.t. $a_1b_1c_1=\frac 1{27}, a_1+a_2+a_3 = 1$ and $a_1b_1+a_2b_3 \geq \eta:=\frac 13$ (+ cyclic shifts)?
By cyclic shifts, I mean cycling $a\to b\to c\to a$, e.g. $b_1+b_2+b_3=1$ and $b_1c_1+b_2c_3\geq \frac 13$, and so on. (So everything becomes symmetric.)
Geometrically, this corresponds to cutting up a unit cube $[0,1]^3$ into 27 regions via 2 cuts on each axis, where the block $B_0$ containing $(0,0,0)$ has volume $\frac 1{27}$, and I want the area of two chosen regions in each face of the cube (one region is a face of the block $B_0$). I have tried to illustrate this in the following diagram:

($B_0$ is visible as the block in the lower left corner; its volume is $\frac 1{27}$. I want the blue, red, green regions --- each on one face, consisting of 2 rectangles --- to have area $\geq \frac 13$ each)


Intuitively, I expect the "optimal" configuration to be with all $a_i=b_i=c_i= \frac 13$, in which case the area in each face is $\frac 29$, which is not enough. (In other words, I expect the answer to the titular question to be "NO".) However, I have not been able to prove this conjecture.
(This is not a homework problem; I was doing a probability puzzle, and just happened to draw this geometric picture above (the cube and 27 regions and so forth) and then got curious about this problem, but couldn't solve it. I use the contest math tag not because it's from a contest, but simply because it gives me a similar vibe.)
Lastly, Question 2: what is the maximum $\eta$ in place of $\frac 13$ s.t. there exist solutions? For instance, $\eta = \frac 29$ works by taking all $a_i,b_i,c_i = \frac 13$. So I conjecture that $\eta = \frac 29$ is optimal.

Did you want $b_1+b_2+b_3=1$, instead of $1/27$?

@HackR ah yes, oops. I fixed it

Is the property $a_i b_i c_i = \frac{1}{27}$ true only for $i=1$ or is it true for $i \in { 1,2,3 }$?

@Kraken only true for $i=1$. I am only cyclically permuting $a\to b\to c \to a$, not the indices.

@Kraken the comment was incorrect and not directed at you. I had missed the OP's clarification, ....

I can prove it's impossible when $\max{a_1,b_1,c_1}\leq \frac 23. $ If it is possible, the maximum should be near $1$ and the minimum should be near $\frac 19$

@dezdichado if it’s not too ugly to write up, I would appreciate seeing that in an answer, even if it doesn’t answer the question fully!

@D.R. actually I was mistaken it looks like. What I know for sure now is this is impossible if the "dummy" variables have $a_2=a_3$ and same for the other two. This makes me think the general case is also impossible.

I think the answer is No.
We may suppose that $a_1\le b_1\le c_1$. Then, we have $a_1\le\frac 13\le c_1$ since $(\frac{1}{3})^3=a_1b_1c_1\ge a_1^3$ and $(\frac{1}{3})^3=a_1b_1c_1\le c_1^3$.
Let $p:=a_1,q:=a_2,r:=b_1,s:=b_2,t:=c_2$.
Then, we can write
$$a_3=1-p-q,b_3=1-r-s,c_1=\frac{1}{27pr},c_3=1-\frac{1}{27pr}-t$$
We want to solve the following system
$$\begin{cases}p,q,r,s,t\gt 0
\\ p\le\frac 13\le \frac{1}{27pr}
\\1-p-q\gt 0
\\1-r-s\gt 0
\\1-\frac{1}{27pr}-t>0
\\pr+q(1-r-s) \geq \frac 13
\\\frac{1}{27p}+s(1-\frac{1}{27pr}-t)\geq \frac 13
\\\frac{1}{27r}+t(1-p-q)\geq \frac 13\end{cases}$$
which can be written as
$$\begin{cases}p,q,r,s,t\gt 0
\\ p\le\frac 13
\\\frac{1}{27p}\lt r\le \frac{1}{9p}\ \ \text{($\frac{1}{27p}\lt r$ since $0\lt t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}$)}
\\1-r-s\gt 0
\\t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}
\\\frac{1}{27p}+s(1-\frac{1}{27pr}-t)\geq \frac 13
\\\frac{\frac 13-pr}{1-r-s}\le q\le\min(1-p,1-p-\frac{r-\frac{1}{9}}{3rt})\end{cases}$$
Suppose that $r\le\frac 19$. Then, we have $\frac{1}{27p}\lt r\le\frac 19$ which implies $p\gt \frac 13$. This contradicts $p\le\frac 13$. So, we have to have $r\gt\frac 19$ and
$$\frac{\frac 13-pr}{1-r-s}\le 1-p-\frac{r-\frac{1}{9}}{3rt}$$
which is equivalent to
$$t\bigg(1-3pr-3(1-r-s)(1-p)\bigg)\le \underbrace{\bigg(\frac 19-r\bigg)}_{\text{negative}}\times\underbrace{\frac{1-r-s}{r}}_{\text{positive}}$$
The RHS is negative, so we have to have $1-3pr-3(1-r-s)(1-p)\lt 0$ and
$$\frac{(\frac 19-r)(1-r-s)}{r(1-3pr-3(1-r-s)(1-p))}\le t$$
From $t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}$, we have to have
$$\frac{(\frac 19-r)(1-r-s)}{r(1-3pr-3(1-r-s)(1-p))}\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\underbrace{(1-r-s)}_{\text{positive}}\bigg(3(27pr-1)(1-p)-27p(r-\frac 19)\bigg)\gt \underbrace{(27pr-1)}_{\text{positive}}\times\underbrace{(1-3pr)}_{\text{positive}}$$
The RHS is positive, so we have to have $3(27pr-1)(1-p)-27p(r-\frac 19)\gt 0$ and
$$1-r-s\gt \frac{(27pr-1)(1-3pr)}{3(27pr-1)(1-p)-27p(r-\frac 19)}$$
i.e.
$$(0\lt)\ s\lt 1-r-\frac{(27pr-1)(1-3pr)}{3(27pr-1)(1-p)-27p(r-\frac 19)}$$
So, two variables $p,r$ at least have to satisfy
$$\begin{cases}0\lt p\le\frac 13
\\3(27pr-1)(1-p)-27p(r-\frac 19)=-3(\color{red}{27p^2r-18pr-2p+1})\gt 0
\\0\lt 1-r-\frac{(27pr-1)(1-3pr)}{3(27pr-1)(1-p)-27p(r-\frac 19)}=\frac{(1-3 p ) (54 p r^2 - 27 p r - 3 r + 2)}{3 (\color{red}{27 p^2 r - 18 p r - 2 p + 1})}\end{cases}$$
which can be simplified as
$$\begin{cases}0\lt p\le\frac 13
\\27p^2r-18pr-2p+1<0
\\54pr^2- 27pr - 3r + 2<0\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}0\lt p\le\frac 13
\\\frac{2p-1}{9p(3p-2)}\lt r
\\\frac{9p+1-\sqrt{(27 p - 1) (3 p - 1)}}{36p}\lt r\lt \frac{9p+1+\sqrt{(27 p - 1) (3 p - 1)}}{36p}
\\27 p - 1<0\end{cases}$$
However, there is no $p$ satisfying both $0\lt p\lt\frac{1}{27}$ and
$$\frac{2p-1}{9p(3p-2)}\lt \frac{9p+1+\sqrt{(27 p - 1) (3 p - 1)}}{36p}$$
Therefore, we can say that the answer is No.$\ \blacksquare$

Added 1 :
I think $\eta=\frac 29$ is not optimal. For the case $\gt \frac 29$, there is a solution. For example, $a_1=\frac{3}{10}$, $a_2=\frac{69}{100}$, $a_3=\frac{1}{100}$, $b_1=\frac{3}{20}$, $b_2=\frac{74}{125}$, $b_3=\frac{129}{500}$, $c_1=\frac{200}{243}$, $c_2=\frac{1}{100}$, $c_3=\frac{4057}{24300}$. This means that for the case $\ge \frac{337609}{1518750}$ which is larger than $\frac 29$, there is a solution.

Added 2 :
Question 2 :
The optimal value is between $0.275981$ and $0.275982$.
Under the condition that $\frac 29\lt \eta\lt\frac 13$, let us consider the following system
$$\begin{cases}(1):0\lt p\le\frac 13
\\(2):\frac{1}{27p}\lt r\le \frac{1}{9p}
\\(3):0\lt t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}
\\(4):\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-\frac{1}{27pr}-t}\le s\lt 1-r
\\(5):\frac{\eta-pr}{1-r-s}\le q\le\min(1-p,1-p-\frac{r-\frac{1}{27\eta}}{\frac{rt}{\eta}})
\end{cases}$$
Case 1 : $r\le \frac{1}{27\eta}$
$$\begin{cases}(1):0\lt p\le\frac 13
\\(2):\frac{1}{27p}\lt r\le \frac{1}{9p}
\\(3):0\lt t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}
\\(4):\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-\frac{1}{27pr}-t}\le s\lt 1-r
\\(5):\frac{\eta-pr}{1-r-s}\le q\le 1-p
\\(6):s\le 1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-p}
\\(7):t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}-\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-p}}
\\(8):\eta-\frac{1}{27p}\gt 0\end{cases}$$
We see that $q$ satisfying $(5)$ exists iff $\frac{\eta-pr}{1-r-s}\le 1-p$, i.e. $s\le 1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-p}(\lt 1-r)$. So, from $(4)$, such $s$ exists iff $\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-\frac{1}{27pr}-t}\lt 1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-p}$, i.e. $$t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}-\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-p}}\tag7$$
Suppose that $\eta-\frac{1}{27p}\le 0$. Then, $p\le\frac{1}{27\eta}$. So, $\eta\le \frac{1}{27p}\lt r\le\frac{1}{27\eta}$. This implies $\eta\lt\frac{\sqrt 3}{9}$ which is a contradiction. So, we have to have $\eta-\frac{1}{27p}\gt 0$.
So, our system has a solution iff the following system has a solution :
$$\begin{cases}0\lt r\le \frac{1}{27\eta}
\\\frac{1}{27\eta}\lt p\le\frac 13
\\0\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}-\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-p}}\end{cases}$$
However, even for $\eta=\frac 14$, this system has no solutions (see here).
Case 2 : $r\gt \frac{1}{27\eta}$
By a similar argument, we have
$$\begin{cases}0\lt p\le\frac 13
\\\frac{1}{27p}\lt r\le \frac{1}{9p}
\\0\lt t\lt \min(1-\frac{1}{27pr},1-\frac{1}{27pr}-\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{ 1-p-\frac{r-\frac{1}{27\eta}}{\frac{rt}{\eta}}}})
\\\frac{27r\eta-1}{27r(1-p-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-r})}\lt t
\\1-p-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-r}\gt 0
\end{cases}$$

If $\eta-\frac{1}{27p}\le 0$, then our system has a solution iff the following system has a solution :
$$\begin{cases}0\lt p\le\frac{1}{27\eta}
\\\frac{1}{27p}\lt r\lt\frac{1-p-\eta}{1-2p}
\\\frac{27r\eta-1}{27r(1-p-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-r})}\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}\end{cases}$$ For $\eta=0.275981$, this system has solutions (see here), but for $\eta=0.275982$, it has no solutions (see here).

If $\eta-\frac{1}{27p}\gt 0$, then our system has a solution iff the following system has a solution :
$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{27\eta}\lt p\le\frac 13
\\\frac{1}{27p}\lt r\le \min(\frac{1}{9p},\frac{1-p-\eta}{1-2p})
\\0\lt\frac{27r\eta-1}{27r(1-p-\frac{\eta-pr}{1-r})}\lt t\lt 1-\frac{1}{27pr}-\frac{\eta-\frac{1}{27p}}{1-r-\frac{\eta-pr}{ 1-p-\frac{r-\frac{1}{27\eta}}{\frac{rt}{\eta}}}}
\end{cases}$$ For $\eta=0.275981$, this system has solutions (see here), but for $\eta=0.275982$, it has no solutions (see here).


We have considered all the cases, so we can finally conclude that the optimal value is between $0.275981$ and $0.275982$.

interesting that such a simple sounding geometric problem produces algebra so complicated. Do you know if your proof can extend to cover cases of the $\geq \frac 13$ bound lowered to say $> \frac 29$?

@D.R. : I think $\eta=\frac 29$ is not optimal. See what I added. I will keep thinking.

@D.R. Computer calculations suggest that the solution exists when $\eta_0\approx 0.275981$; on the other hand, using rather simple inequalities, I lowered the bound to $\eta\le \frac {3+\sqrt{5}}{18}=0.2908\dots$, see my answer.
But I guess this bound can be improved, because my proof is based on a rather loose inequality.

@D.R. : I added an answer to Question 2.

It seems I can improve the upper bound for $\eta$, so I am going to update the answer.
Computer calculations suggest that the solution exists when $\eta_0\approx 0.275981$, see the end of the answer. On the other hand, we shall show that if the solution exists then $\eta\le \frac {3+\sqrt{5}}{18}=0.2908\dots$. I guess this bound can be improved, because my answer is based on the following rather loose inequality.
Let $0<\eta\le 1$. It it easy to show that for each $t\in [0,\eta]$ we have $$\sqrt{\eta-t}\ge \sqrt{\eta}-\frac t{\sqrt{\eta}}.$$
Suppose first that each of the numbers $a_1b_1$, $b_1c_1$, and $c_1a_1$ is at most $\eta$. Then, by the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means, we have
$$a_2+b_3\ge 2\sqrt{a_2b_3}\ge 2\sqrt{\eta-a_1b_1}\ge 2\sqrt{\eta}-\frac {2a_1b_1}{\sqrt{\eta}},$$
$$b_2+c_3\ge 2\sqrt{b_2c_3}\ge 2\sqrt{\eta-b_1c_1}\ge 2\sqrt{\eta}-\frac {2b_1c_1}{\sqrt{\eta}},$$
$$c_2+a_3\ge 2\sqrt{c_2a_3}\ge 2\sqrt{\eta-c_1a_1}\ge 2\sqrt{\eta}-\frac {2c_1a_1}{\sqrt{\eta}}.$$
Adding these inequalities, we obtain
$$3-(a_1+b_1+c_1)\ge 6\sqrt{\eta}-\frac {2a_1b_1}{\sqrt{\eta}}-\frac {2b_1c_1}{\sqrt{\eta}}-
\frac {2c_1a_1}{\sqrt{\eta}}.$$
Put $t_1=a_1b_1$, $t_2=b_1c_1$, $t_3=c_1a_1$, and $f(t)=2\sqrt{\eta}-\frac {2t}{\sqrt{\eta}}+\frac 1{27t}.$
Then
$$3\ge f(t_1)+f(t_2)+f(t_3).$$
Since the function $f(t)$ is convex, by Jensen's inequality,
$$f(t_1)+f(t_2)+f(t_3)\ge 3f\left(\frac{t_1+t_2+t_3}3\right).$$
Let us minimize the sum $t_1+t_2+t_3$. We have $t_1t_2t_3=\frac 1{27^2}$, so $t_3=\frac 1{27^2t_1t_2}$.
So, when the sum $t_1+t_2$ is fixed, the minimum of $t_3$ is attained when the maximum of $t_1t_2$ is attained. By the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means, this happens when $t_1=t_2$.
So we have to minimize the sum $2t_1+\frac 1{27^2t_1^2}$. The derivative of the sum is zero iff $t_1=\frac 19$. Then $t_2=t_1=\frac 19$ and $t_3=\frac 1{27^2t_1t_2}=\frac 19$. So $t_1+t_2+t_3\ge \frac 13$.
Since the function $f(t)$ is decreasing, we have
$$3\ge f(t_1)+f(t_2)+f(t_3)\ge 3f\left(\frac{t_1+t_2+t_3}3\right)\ge $$
$$3f\left(\frac 19\right)=6\sqrt{\eta}-\frac {2}{3\sqrt{\eta}}+1.$$
Then $9\eta-3\sqrt{\eta}-1\le 0$, that is $3\sqrt{\eta}\le \frac {1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\eta\le \frac {3+\sqrt{5}}{18}=0.2908\dots$.
Otherwise, applying cyclic shifts, if needed, we can suppose that $a_1b_1\ge\eta$. Increasing $a_3$ and $b_2$, if needed, we can assume that $a_2=b_3=0$. Then $a_3=1-a_1$ and $b_2=1-b_1$. Therefore
$$b_1c_1+(1-b_1)c_3\ge\eta\mbox{ and }c_1a_1+c_2(1-a_1)\ge\eta.$$
Thus
$$c_3\ge \frac{\eta-b_1c_1}{1-b_1}\mbox{ and }c_2\ge \frac{\eta-c_1a_1}{1-a_1}$$
$$1-c_1=c_2+c_3\ge \frac{\eta-b_1c_1}{1-b_1}+\frac{\eta-c_1a_1}{1-a_1}.$$
The function $g(t)=\frac{\eta-tc_1}{1-t}$ has the second derivative $2\cdot\frac{\eta-c_1}{(1-t)^3}$.
We suppose that $\eta\ge c_1$, because otherwise $$\eta\le \frac 1{27a_1b_1}\le \frac 1{27\eta},$$
so $\eta\le\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}=0.1924\dots$.
Then the second derivative $g''(t)$ is nonnegative, so the function $g(t)$ is convex. Then by Jensen's inequality,
$$1-c_1\ge 2g\left(\frac{a_1+b_1}2\right).$$
Put $s=a_1+b_1$. Then
$$1-c_1\ge 2\frac{\eta-\frac {s}2c_1}{1-\frac s2}$$
$$4\eta\le 2-s-2c_1+3sc_1$$
We suppose that $c_1\le \tfrac 13$ because otherwise
$$1\le 3c_1\le\frac 3{27a_1b_1}\le \frac 1{9\eta},$$
so $\eta\le \frac 19=0.1111\dots$.
Since
$$s=a_1+b_1\ge 2\sqrt{a_1b_1}=\frac 2{\sqrt{27c_1}},$$
$$4\eta\le 2-2c_1+(3c_1-1)\frac{2}{\sqrt{27c_1}}$$
The derivative of the right-hand side with respect to $c_1$ is
$$\frac 19\cdot \left(\sqrt{3}-3\sqrt{c_1}\right)\left( 6c_1+3\sqrt{c_1}+1\right).$$
Since $c_1\le \tfrac 13$, the right-hand side is increasing. Since $c_1\le \tfrac 1{27\eta}$, we have
$$2\eta\le 1-\frac 1{27\eta}+\left(\frac 1{9\eta}-1\right)\cdot \sqrt{\eta}$$
$$54\eta^2+27\eta^{3/2}-27\eta-3\eta^{1/2}+1\le 0.$$
Then, according to Mathcad calculations, $\eta\in (\approx 0.024677,\approx 0.275981)$.
More calculations suggest that if $\eta_0\approx 0.275981$ is the biggest root of the left-hand side polynomial then we have a solution
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{\eta_0} & 0 & 1-\sqrt{\eta_0} \\
\sqrt{\eta_0} & 1-\sqrt{\eta_0} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{27\eta_0} & \frac 12-\frac{1}{54\eta_0} & \frac 12-\frac{1}{54\eta_0}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

So the first part is showing that if $\max a_ib_i\leq\eta$ and there is a solution, then  $\eta$ satisfies the "quartic" and the second part is showing that unconditionally there is a solution if for any value $\eta_0$ not exceeding the largest root of the previous quartic inequality ?
